# mongodb sum length of all lists in a database

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, database

I'm pretty new to mongo aggregations and I've been getting some relatively unhelpful errors and I haven't quite been able to find any clear examples. The short is that I have a collection `user_data`, the document is arranged like so:

```
{
    _id: ObjectID,
    text: [#Documents],
    username: "<string>",
    metadata: {<fields>}
}
```

Basically, I'm looking to count the total number of documents present in this collection. The documents are all under the text field. I feel very close merging the `$sum`, and `$size` selectors, and this is what I have now:

```
db.user_data.aggregate([{$sum: {$size: "$text"}}])
```

Which seems at least on the right track, but running this I get this error message:

```
command failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$sum'",
    "code" : 16436,
    "ok" : 0
} : aggregate failed at src/mongo/shell/assert.js:13
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Again, very new to aggregations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the right idea to use `$sum` and `$size`, but you need to put that inside a [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operator:

```js
db.user_data.aggregate([
    {$group: {
        _id: null,
        count: {$sum: {$size: "$text"}}
    }}
])
```

The `_id: null` is used to group over the entire collection rather than on a specific field.